# Processing files from an <input> element

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have the following Svelte script to upload a file

```html
<script lang="typescript">
    let files = [];
    export let multiple = true;
    function handleChange(e) {
        files = Array.from(e.target.files);
        // process the contents of each file
    }
</script>


Upload a csv of the measurements:

<input type="file" {multiple} onChange={handleChange} />

<div>
    {#each files as f}
        {f.name}, {f.size}, {f.type},
    {/each}
</div>
```

I would like to access the contents of each file and process them by routing them to an endpoint. Which data should I reference in the body of a fetch post request function to the endpoint?

Just doing

```html
fetch("endpoint", {method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify(files)})
```

inside the handleChange function does not work. I have also tried wrapping the input in a form element but this doesn't work.

Comment: If you log `files` inside `handleChange()` - what do you get? (+ I think the multiple shouldn't be in curly braces..?)

Comment: + it's `on:change=` instead of `onChange`

Comment: for reading the .csv files [Papa Parse](https://www.papaparse.com/) might be of help

Comment: @Corrl i have changed the onChange to on:change and log files, however, nothing is logged.

Comment: That's strange, have a look at [this REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/b6cb2154b4b247e78d08c2d7d1611867?version=3.44.1) where it works (you don't have to convert the FileList to an array, you can iterate it with a for-of-loop)

Comment: @Corrl thank you, that helps, now i can see the file title, but i would like to see the contents. How is that possible?

Comment: You can either use the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) if you know how the files look like (which seperator is used) or probably better use a library like Papa Parse, which I commented before

Comment: @Corrl I am sorry but I don't understand how to use Papa or FileReader to upload the file. I understand it can be used to parse an uploaded file.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with Paparse in Svelte by using the papa.parse function:

```html
<script lang="typescript">
    import papa from 'papaparse';

    function handleChange(event) {
        let files = event.target.files;
        for (let f of files) {
            papa.parse(f, {
                header: true,
                complete: function (results) {
                    console.log(results);
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>



Upload a csv of the measurements:

<input type="file" on:change={handleChange} />
```